# replace cells of a specific sheet with cells based on a table in other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

How could I improve below code to replace cells based to a table named "Table1" (which is in sheet "DataMatch") but only replace in a specific sheet called "data" the cells A1:B10. Do not do anything for the other sheets. The code below is not working.

```
    Sub replacecells1()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Integer
Dim rplcList As Integer
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant

'Create variable to point to your table
  Set tbl = Worksheets("DataMatch").ListObjects("Table1")

'Create an Array out of the Table's Data
  Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange
  myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)

'Designate Columns for Find/Replace data
  fndList = 1
  rplcList = 2

'Loop through each item in Array lists
For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 2)

      Sheets("Data").Range("A1:B10").Replace What:=myArray(fndList, x), Replacement:=myArray(rplcList, x), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

  Next

End Sub
```

My "Data" Sheet is (where the replace must happen):

[image]

My "MatchData" sheet (where have the table1)is:

[image]

Comment: if I understand your question correctly, replace everything from `For Each sht ... ` to  `... Next sht` with `Sheets("Data").Range("A1:B10").Replace ... and rest of the existing replace arguments`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated the code above - please have a look. But i get an error : subscript out of arrange. Can you check if something is wrong?

Comment: you missed the last part of my comment. `... and rest of the existing replace arguments` (or maybe it wasn't clear). In other words, the replace statement you originally had there, add those same arguments to the replace statement I gave you against `Sheets("Data").Range("A1:B10")`

Comment: I am getting lost.. sorry. Could you please edit my code above and suggest a answer? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to replace everything inside the myArray loop with the following code to only replace the information in the `Range(A1:B10)` in the `Data` worksheet

```
 For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 2)

      Sheets("Data").Range("A1:B10").Replace What:=myArray(fndList, x), Replacement:=myArray(rplcList, x), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

  Next
```

Comment: Still gives me script out of range, I edit my first code for you to see what am I missing.

Comment: see edit, I thought you originally wrote that the sheet name was "Data". I changed it to "DataMatch"

Comment: DataMatch is the sheet with the Table1 (data to use in the replace); Data is the sheet I really want to use the command replace. Please see my updated code on top. Something is missing there right?

Comment: how many columns in your table? can you post a screenshot of your table?

Comment: I added some prints to my question with sheet i want to change and the sheet which has the table1 . thanks again!

Comment: is `Table1` an actual Excel Table or is it a named range called `Table1`? I just tested the code on my end as if it was an actual Excel Table and it worked. The only suggestion I would make is to set `LookAt:=xlWhole`, so that it does not keep searching for parts of words after they are replaced.